# How to prevent being able to access a field of a QuerySet object if the fieldname was not provided in the only() method?

Tags: django, django-models

Let's pretend I have this Django model:

```
class Person(models.Model)
    name = models.CharField()
    age = models.IntegerField()
```

Then I do this query on the model:

```
queryset = Person.objects.filter(name="Joe").only("name") # Notice that I want to only select the name field.
object_list = list(queryset) # Purposefully triggered the database hit by calling list on it.
```

How do I prevent being able to do this?:

```
object_list[0].age # Accessing a field that I did not include in the "only" method triggers an additional hit to the database.
```

I would like it to raise an Exception or just do nothing instead of hitting the database for the second time.

Update: I have answered my own question but I would like others to post their answers to see if they have a solution that is better.

Answer (score 0):

Overwrite the model's refresh_from_db method and raise an AttributeError if it is called.

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    age = models.IntegerField()

    def refresh_from_db(self, using=None, fields=None):
        """
        This method was overwritten because of the issues addressed in these tickets:
            https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/26481
            https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/22492
            https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/30874
        """
        raise AttributeError(
            f'Cannot access {self.__class__.__name__}.{fields[0]} because the '
            'fieldname was not provided as an argument in the QuerySet.only() '
            'method.'
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

Install and use a third-party package called [django-seal](https://github.com/charettes/django-seal).